# NextJS - Passing state to children as props in custom app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have this `./pages/_app.js` [from the official docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#custom-app):

```
import App, { Container } from 'next/app'

class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {}

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }

    return { pageProps }
  }

  render () {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props

    return (
      <Container>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

I want to pass state from MyApp to every page it renders, but can't figure how. I tried this:

```
const childProps = {
  ...
}

<Container>
  <Component {...childProps} />
</Container>
```

and got an error:

`React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.`

Comment: Something further up or down in your code is rendering two children when the Next.js component only can handle one. The problem is not in the code that you posted.

Comment: You're right @AndyRay! It was a `<Link><Icon />text</Link>` which had two children (remnants of react-router Link). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass what you want just as you pass usual props

```
<Component whatyouwant={propsyouwant} />
```

For example: this is how I passed MobileDetect props to every component in my app:

```
class MyApp extends App {

  static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {

    let pageProps = {}
    const { req } = ctx
    var MobileDetect = require('mobile-detect')
    const md = new MobileDetect(req ? req.headers['user-agent'] : "")
    const phone = md.phone()
    const tablet = md.tablet()

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }
    return {  pageProps,  
              phone: phone, 
              tablet: tablet }
  }


  render () {

    const {Component, pageProps, phone, tablet} = this.props
    return (
      <Container>
        <Provider store={reduxStore}> 
            <Nav /> 
            <Component {...pageProps} phone={phone} tablet={tablet} />
            <Footer />
        </Provider>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default withReduxStore(MyApp)
```

Comment: Thank you! I’m accepting this as the answer, but the reason I was having the error is in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was

```
<Link>
  <Icon />
  text
</Link>
```

in the rendered page (not `_app.js`).
The Link had two children (remnants of react-router Link) instead of one.